# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - checkValidity

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I am busy for school with AJAX, jQuery and HTML 5. I need to build a chat and everything works except this part of posting the posts.

This is the code for the form:

```
<form id="chatForm">
        <div id="chatHead">
            <input type="text" name="chatName" id="userName" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
            <input type="button" value="Start" name="chatButton" id="chatButton" />
        </div>

        <div id="chatBox"></div>

        <div id="chatFoot">
            <input type="text" name="chatMessage" id="chatMessage" size="63" placeholder="Bericht" />
            <input type="submit" name="chatSend" id="chatSend" value="Send" disabled="disabled" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

This is the function for inserting the post:

```
 function postChat() {
    $(chatForm).submit(function () {
        return false;
    });

    if ($(chatForm)[0].checkValidity()) {
        if (!this.checkValidity()) {

        }
        else {
            var Naam = $(chatName).val(),
                Bericht = $(chatMessage).val();

            $.get(phpScript, {action: "addMessage", name: Naam, message: Bericht})
                .done(function () {
                    postChat();
                    startChat("system");
                });
            $(chatMessage).val("");
        }
    }}
```

I always get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

It says it goes wrong in this part of the code:

```
if (!this.checkValidity()) {

    }
```

I don't know exactly what this means but it is to ensure that the system doesn't keep posting the messages.

If someone also can explain me what this exactly does I will be very graceful.

Comment: it means that there's no function called checkValidity. `this` probably refers to something else than what you expect

Comment: is there anyway to find out where the this value refers to?

Comment: console.log(this); an then you will see it in browsers F12 (press f12 key) console

Comment: Edited my answer. Check it.

Comment: If you open the debugger of the browser you can inspect the values of all identifiers. In IE you can open with F12, in Chrome with ctrl-shift-i (on win).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you think word "this" is?

```
if (!this.checkValidity()) {

}
```

- Word "this" refers to an object that has not checkValidity()
  function.
- Your code looks wrong, and has an recursion (you are calling fo postChat() function inside itself)

Maybe you better rewrite you logic with this skeleton:

Note: remove  **disabled="disabled"** from submit button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* Run code only when DOM is ready (document loaded) */
    $('#chatForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        /* Run code when user sumbits the form (pressing button or ENTER */.
        e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent form to be sended

        /*
            NOW HERE DO VALIDATION AND AJAX POSTS
            As example I inserted part of your code.
         */

        if ($('#chatForm')[0].checkValidity()) {
            var Naam = $('#userName').val(), Bericht = $('#chatMessage').val();

            $.get(phpScript, {action: "addMessage", name: Naam, message: Bericht})
                .done(function () {
                    startChat("system");
            });

            $(chatMessage).val("");
        } else {
            alert("Validation failed");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: no then the error would have been that undefine has no property called checkValidity and in JS this is always something

Comment: well I thought so to. But a classmate of me has shown me his code and it works at him.

Comment: If I use your code and I try to submit for the first time it doens't post a message and I can't enter anything in the inputfield anymore.